# In Washington state, can a Home Owners Association allow home owners to keep pets, but not renters?

Tags: washington, hoa

My friend lives in an apartment building in Washington where the bylaws allow home owners to keep dogs and cats, but states that renters are not allowed to keep any pets. Is this legal according to Washington laws? I understand that Homeowners Associations may choose to ban or allow pets as they please, but are they allowed to only permit home owners to keep them?

Comment: Does the HOA own the apartment?

Comment: @RonBeyer no, directly owned by the owner.

Comment: @RonBeyer How it works is that the HOA has a _restrictive covenant_ on the home/apartment. The deed to the apartment will have HOA rules and financial assessments written into it, as well as a procedure via voting to amend HOA rules.

Comment: @user71659 I know how an HOA works, I'm just wondering what the wording in the HOA bylaws are specifically targeted at non-owners or subletters. Usually the HOA applies to the owner of the property, which are usually passed to the subletters, but it's odd to me that there would be wording specifically restricting an owners tenant and not the owner themselves.

Comment: @RonBeyer Then why did you ask whether the HOA owns the apartment? An HOA would never own individual properties.

Comment: @RonBeyer yes, there's wording specifically singling out renters and pets.

Comment: @user71659 Yes, an HOA can own a property, it's not as common but it has happened.

Comment: @JonathanReez Perhaps the homeowner owns the pets and the renter is just looking after them for the homeowner?  (said mostly in jest, but that could actually be a loophole)

Comment: Possibly they think that the lesser investment of the renter, who can vanish at any time, will give him sufficiently less concern that his pets are more likely to be a nuisance.

Comment: Reading just the title, I thought it asked whether home owners could keep renters.